# Gekko: MINLP - Error options.json file not found

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I am trying to solve a MINLP problem using first the IPOPT solver to get an initial solution then the APOPT to get the mixed integer solution. However, I get the following error when calling the APOPT solver:

> Error: Exception: Access Violation                                                                                      At line 359 of file ./f90/cqp.f90                                                                                        Traceback: not available, compile with -ftrace=frame or -ftrace=full                                                                                                                                                                            Error: 'results.json' not found. Check above for additional error details                                               Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        File "optimisation_stack.py", line 244, in                                                                        Optimise_G(t,ob, jofbuses, q, qc, s, oa, k, l, T, G_previous, C, Y, G_previous, G_max, G_min)                         File "optimisation_stack.py", line 134, in Optimise_G                                                                     sol = MINLP(xinit, A, B, A_eq, B_eq, LB ,UB, t, ob, jofbuses, q, qc, s, oa, k, l, T, G_previous, C, Y, G_previous)    File "optimisation_stack.py", line 215, in MINLP                                                                          m_APOPT.solve(disp = False)                                                                                           File "C:\Users\Zineb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py", line 2227, in solve        self.load_JSON()                                                                                                      File "C:\Users\Zineb\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_post_solve.py", line 13, in load_JSON                                                                                                                      f = open(os.path.join(self._path,'options.json'))                                                                   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Users\Zineb\AppData\Local\Temp\tmptdgafg1zgk_model1\options.json'

My code is the following, I tried to simplify it as much as possible :

```
import numpy as np 
from gekko import GEKKO 

# Define matrices A,A_eq, and vectors b, b_eq for the optimization

def Optimise_G(t,ob, jofbuses, q, qc, s, oa, k, l, T, G_next, C, Y, G_previous, G_max, G_min):
    Mbig_1 = T*C
    Mbig_2 = C
    nb_phases = len(G_next)
    b_max = len(t)
    no_lanegroups = len(q)

    A_eq = np.zeros(((nb_phases+1)*b_max + 1, (3*nb_phases+3)*b_max+nb_phases))
    for i in range(nb_phases):
        A_eq[0][i] = 1

    #B_eq = np.zeros(((nb_phases+1)*b_max + 1, 1))
    B_eq = np.zeros((nb_phases+1)*b_max + 1)
    B_eq[0] = C - sum(Y[0:nb_phases])

    counter_eq = 0

    # G(i)=Ga(i,b)+Gb(i,b)+Gc(i,b)
    for b in range(b_max):
        for i in range(nb_phases):
            counter_eq = counter_eq + 1
            A_eq[counter_eq][i] = 1
            A_eq[counter_eq][nb_phases*(b+1)+ i] = -1
            A_eq[counter_eq][nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases*(b+1) + i] = -1
            A_eq[counter_eq][2*nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases*(b+1) + i] = -1


    # ya(b)+y(b)+y(c)=1
    for b in range(b_max):
        counter_eq = counter_eq + 1
        A_eq[counter_eq][3*nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases + b] = 1
        A_eq[counter_eq][(3*nb_phases+1)*b_max + nb_phases + b] = 1
        A_eq[counter_eq][(3*nb_phases+2)*b_max + nb_phases + b] = 1
        B_eq[counter_eq] = 1
    

    A = np.zeros((no_lanegroups + (2*3*nb_phases+4)*b_max, (3*nb_phases+3)*b_max+nb_phases))
    B = np.zeros(no_lanegroups + (2*3*nb_phases+4)*b_max)

    counter = -1

    # Sum Gi (i in Ij)>=Gj,min
    for j in range(no_lanegroups):
        counter = counter + 1
        for i in range(k[j], l[j]+1):
            A[counter][i-1] = -1
        B[counter] = -C*qc[j]/s[j]

    # ya(b)G_lb(i)<=Ga(i,b), yb(b)G_lb(i)<=Gb(i,b), yc(b)G_lb(i)<=Gc(i,b)
    for b in range(b_max): 
        for i in range(nb_phases):
            counter = counter + 1
            A[counter][nb_phases*(b+1)+i] = -1
            A[counter][3*nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases + b] = G_min[i]
            B[counter] = 0
        
            counter = counter + 1
            A[counter][nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases*(b+1) + i] = -1
            A[counter][(3*nb_phases+1)*b_max + nb_phases + b] = G_min[i]
            B[counter] = 0
        
            counter = counter + 1
            A[counter][2*nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases*(b+1) +i] = -1
            A[counter][(3*nb_phases+2)*b_max + nb_phases + b] = G_min[i]
            B[counter] = 0
        
    # ya(b)Gmax(i)>=Ga(i,b), yb(b)Gmax(i)>=Gb(i,b), yc(b)Gmax(i)>=Gc(i,b)
    for b in range(b_max):
        for i in range(nb_phases):
            counter = counter + 1
            A[counter][nb_phases*(b+1) +i] = 1
            A[counter][3*nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases + b] = -G_max[i]
            B[counter] = 0
        
            counter = counter + 1
            A[counter][nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases*(b+1) + i] = 1
            A[counter][(3*nb_phases+1)*b_max + nb_phases + b] = -G_max[i]
            B[counter] = 0
        
            counter = counter + 1
            A[counter][2*nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases*(b+1) +i] = 1
            A[counter][(3*nb_phases+2)*b_max + nb_phases + b] = -G_max[i]
            B[counter] = 0  
        
    # (1-yc(b))t(b)<=(T-1)C+sum(Gi(1:l(jofbuses(b))))+sum(Y(1:l(jofbuses(b))-1))
    for b in range(b_max):
        counter = counter + 1
        A[counter][0:l[jofbuses[b]-1]] = -np.ones((1,l[jofbuses[b]-1]))
        A[counter][(3*nb_phases+2)*b_max+nb_phases+b] = -t[b]
        B[counter] = -t[b] + (T-1)*C + sum(Y[0:l[jofbuses[b]-1]-1])

    # (T-1)C+sum(Gi(1:l(jofbuses(b))))+sum(Y(1:l(jofbuses(b))-1))<=yc(b)t(b)+(1-yc(b))Mbig_1
    for b in range(b_max):
        counter = counter + 1
        A[counter][0:l[jofbuses[b]-1]] = np.ones((1,l[jofbuses[b]-1]))
        A[counter][(3*nb_phases+2)*b_max+nb_phases+b] = -t[b] + Mbig_1
        B[counter] = Mbig_1 - (T-1)*C - sum(Y[0:l[jofbuses[b]-1]-1])


    # -Mbig_2(1-yb(b))<=db(b)=right-hand side of Equation (6)
    for b in range(b_max):
        counter = counter + 1
        constant = q[jofbuses[b]-1]/s[jofbuses[b]-1]*(t[b] - (T-1)*C + sum(G_previous[l[jofbuses[b]-1]:nb_phases]) + sum(Y[l[jofbuses[b]-1] -1:nb_phases]))+ (T-1)*C + sum(Y[0:k[jofbuses[b]-1]-1]) - t[b]  
        A[counter][0:k[jofbuses[b]-1]-1] = -np.ones((1,k[jofbuses[b]-1]-1))
        A[counter][(3*nb_phases+1)*b_max + nb_phases + b] = Mbig_2
        B[counter] = constant + Mbig_2


    # db(b)<=Mbig_2 yb(b)
    for b in range(b_max):
        counter = counter + 1
        constant = q[jofbuses[b]-1]/s[jofbuses[b]-1]*(t[b] - (T-1)*C +sum(G_previous[l[jofbuses[b]-1]:nb_phases]) + sum(Y[l[jofbuses[b]-1] -1:nb_phases]))+ (T-1)*C + sum(Y[0:k[jofbuses[b]-1]-1]) - t[b]  
        A[counter][0:k[jofbuses[b]-1]-1] = np.ones((1,k[jofbuses[b]-1]-1))
        A[counter][(3*nb_phases+1)*b_max + nb_phases + b] = -Mbig_2
        B[counter] = -constant
    
    #Lower Bound LB
    LB_zeros = np.zeros(3*b_max*(nb_phases+1))
    G_min = np.array(G_min)
    LB = np.append(G_min, LB_zeros)

    #Upper Bound UB
    UB = np.ones(3*b_max)
    G_max = np.array(G_max)
    for i in range(3*b_max+1):
        UB = np.concatenate((G_max,UB))
    
    xinit = np.array([(a+b)/2 for a, b in zip(UB, LB)])
    sol = MINLP(xinit, A, B, A_eq, B_eq, LB ,UB, t, ob, jofbuses, q, qc, s, oa, k, l, T, G_previous, C, Y, G_previous)
```

The objective function:

```
def objective_fun(x, t, ob, jofbuses, q, qc, s, oa, k, l, T, G_next, C, Y, G_previous):
    nb_phases = len(G_next)
    b_max = len(t)
    no_lanegroups = len(q)
    obj = 0
    obj_a = 0
    obj_b = 0

    G = x[0:nb_phases]

    for j in range(no_lanegroups):
        delay_a = 0.5*q[j]/(1-q[j]/s[j]) * (pow((sum(G_previous[l[j]:nb_phases]) + sum(G[0:k[j]-1]) + sum(Y[l[j]-1:nb_phases]) + sum(Y[0:k[j]-1])),2) + pow(sum(G[l[j]:nb_phases]) + sum(G_next[0:k[j]-1]) + sum(Y[l[j]-1:nb_phases]) + sum(Y[0:k[j]-1]),2))   
    
        obj = obj + oa*delay_a
        obj_a = obj_a + oa*delay_a
         
    for b in range(b_max): 
   
        delay_b1 = x[(3*nb_phases+1)*b_max + nb_phases + b]*(q[jofbuses[b]-1]/s[jofbuses[b]-1] * (t[b] - (T-1)*C + sum(G_previous[l[jofbuses[b]-1]:nb_phases]) + sum(Y[l[jofbuses[b]-1] -1:nb_phases])) + (T-1)*C - t[b] + sum(Y[0:k[jofbuses[b]-1]-1])) 
        delay_b2 = x[(3*nb_phases+2)*b_max + nb_phases + b-1]*(q[jofbuses[b]-1]/s[jofbuses[b]-1] * (t[b] - (T-1)*C - sum(Y[0:l[jofbuses[b]-1]-1])) + T*C + sum(G_next[0:k[jofbuses[b]-1]-1]) + sum(Y[0:k[jofbuses[b]-1]-1]) - t[b]) 
        delay_b3 = sum(x[nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases*b:nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases*b+k[jofbuses[b]-1]-1]) - q[jofbuses[b]-1]/s[jofbuses[b]-1]*sum(x[2*nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases*b:2*nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases*b +l[jofbuses[b]-1]])
        delay_b = delay_b1+delay_b2 +delay_b3 

        obj = obj + delay_b*ob[b]
        obj_b = obj_b + delay_b*ob[b]
    return obj
```

MINLP solver:

```
def MINLP(xinit, A, B, A_eq, B_eq, LB ,UB, t, ob, jofbuses, q, qc, s, oa, k, l, T, G_next, C, Y, G_previous):
    nb_phases = len(G_next)
    b_max = len(t)
    ## First Solver: IPOPT to get an initial guess
    m_IPOPT = GEKKO(remote = False)
    m_IPOPT.options.SOLVER = 3 #(IPOPT)

    # Array Variable
    rows  = nb_phases + 3*b_max*(nb_phases+1)#48
    x_initial = np.empty(rows,dtype=object)

    for i in range(3*nb_phases*b_max+nb_phases+1):
        x_initial[i] = m_IPOPT.Var(value = xinit[i], lb = LB[i], ub = UB[i])#, integer = False)

    for i in range(3*nb_phases*b_max+nb_phases+1, (3*nb_phases+3)*b_max+nb_phases):
        x_initial[i] = m_IPOPT.Var(value = xinit[i], lb = LB[i], ub = UB[i])#, integer = True)

    # Constraints
    m_IPOPT.axb(A,B,x_initial,etype = '<=',sparse=False) 

    m_IPOPT.axb(A_eq,B_eq,x_initial,etype = '=',sparse=False)

    # Objective Function
    f = objective_fun(x_initial, t, ob, jofbuses, q, qc, s, oa, k, l, T, G_next, C, Y, G_previous)
    m_IPOPT.Obj(f)

    #Solver
    m_IPOPT.solve(disp = True)

####################################################################################################
    ## Second Solver: APOPT to solve MINLP
    m_APOPT = GEKKO(remote = False)
    m_APOPT.options.SOLVER = 1 #(APOPT)

    x = np.empty(rows,dtype=object)

    for i in range(3*nb_phases*b_max+nb_phases+1):
        x[i] = m_APOPT.Var(value = x_initial[i], lb = LB[i], ub = UB[i], integer = False)

    for i in range(3*nb_phases*b_max+nb_phases+1, (3*nb_phases+3)*b_max+nb_phases):
        x[i] = m_APOPT.Var(value = x_initial[i], lb = LB[i], ub = UB[i], integer = True)

    # Constraints
    m_APOPT.axb(A,B,x,etype = '<=',sparse=False) 

    m_APOPT.axb(A_eq,B_eq,x,etype = '=',sparse=False)

    # Objective Function
    f = objective_fun(x, t, ob, jofbuses, q, qc, s, oa, k, l, T, G_next, C, Y, G_previous)
    m_APOPT.Obj(f)

    #Solver
    m_APOPT.solve(disp = False)

    return x
```

Define parameters and call Optimise_G:

```
#Define Parameters

C = 120 
T = 31
b_max = 2
G_base = [12,31,12,11,1,41]
G_max = [106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106]
G_min = [7,3,7,10,0,7]
G_previous = [7.3333333, 34.16763, 7.1333333, 10.0, 2.2008602e-16, 47.365703]
Y = [2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3]
jofbuses = [9,3]
k = [3,1,6,4,1,2,5,4,2,3]
l = [3,2,6,5,1,3,6,4,3,4]
nb_phases = 6
oa = 1.25
ob = [39,42]
t = [3600.2, 3603.5]
q = [0.038053758888888886, 0.215206065, 0.11325116416666667, 0.06299876472222223,0.02800455611111111,0.18878488361111112,0.2970903402777778, 0.01876728472222222, 0.2192723663888889, 0.06132227222222222]
qc = [0.04083333333333333, 0.2388888888888889, 0.10555555555555556, 0.0525, 0.030555555555555555, 0.20444444444444446,0.31083333333333335, 0.018333333333333333, 0.12777777777777777, 0.07138888888888889]
s = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]

nb_phases = len(G_base)
G_max = []
for i in range(nb_phases):
    G_max.append(C - sum(Y[0:nb_phases]))

Optimise_G(t,ob, jofbuses, q, qc, s, oa, k, l, T, G_previous, C, Y, G_previous, G_max, G_min)
```

Is there a way to solve this issue?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows version of the APOPT solver crashed and wasn't able to find a solution. However, the online Linux version of APOPT is able to find a solution. Get the latest version of [Gekko (v1.0.0 pre-release) available on GitHub](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/blob/master/gekko/gekko.py). This will be available with `pip install gekko --upgrade` when the new version is published but for now you need to copy the source to `Lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py`. After updating `gekko`, switch to `remote=True` as shown below.

```py
import numpy as np 
from gekko import GEKKO 

# Define matrices A,A_eq, and vectors b, b_eq for the optimization

def Optimise_G(t,ob, jofbuses, q, qc, s, oa, k, l, T, G_next, C, Y, G_previous, G_max, G_min):
    Mbig_1 = T*C
    Mbig_2 = C
    nb_phases = len(G_next)
    b_max = len(t)
    no_lanegroups = len(q)

    A_eq = np.zeros(((nb_phases+1)*b_max + 1, (3*nb_phases+3)*b_max+nb_phases))
    for i in range(nb_phases):
        A_eq[0][i] = 1

    #B_eq = np.zeros(((nb_phases+1)*b_max + 1, 1))
    B_eq = np.zeros((nb_phases+1)*b_max + 1)
    B_eq[0] = C - sum(Y[0:nb_phases])

    counter_eq = 0

    # G(i)=Ga(i,b)+Gb(i,b)+Gc(i,b)
    for b in range(b_max):
        for i in range(nb_phases):
            counter_eq = counter_eq + 1
            A_eq[counter_eq][i] = 1
            A_eq[counter_eq][nb_phases*(b+1)+ i] = -1
            A_eq[counter_eq][nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases*(b+1) + i] = -1
            A_eq[counter_eq][2*nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases*(b+1) + i] = -1


    # ya(b)+y(b)+y(c)=1
    for b in range(b_max):
        counter_eq = counter_eq + 1
        A_eq[counter_eq][3*nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases + b] = 1
        A_eq[counter_eq][(3*nb_phases+1)*b_max + nb_phases + b] = 1
        A_eq[counter_eq][(3*nb_phases+2)*b_max + nb_phases + b] = 1
        B_eq[counter_eq] = 1
    

    A = np.zeros((no_lanegroups + (2*3*nb_phases+4)*b_max, (3*nb_phases+3)*b_max+nb_phases))
    B = np.zeros(no_lanegroups + (2*3*nb_phases+4)*b_max)

    counter = -1

    # Sum Gi (i in Ij)>=Gj,min
    for j in range(no_lanegroups):
        counter = counter + 1
        for i in range(k[j], l[j]+1):
            A[counter][i-1] = -1
        B[counter] = -C*qc[j]/s[j]

    # ya(b)G_lb(i)<=Ga(i,b), yb(b)G_lb(i)<=Gb(i,b), yc(b)G_lb(i)<=Gc(i,b)
    for b in range(b_max): 
        for i in range(nb_phases):
            counter = counter + 1
            A[counter][nb_phases*(b+1)+i] = -1
            A[counter][3*nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases + b] = G_min[i]
            B[counter] = 0
        
            counter = counter + 1
            A[counter][nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases*(b+1) + i] = -1
            A[counter][(3*nb_phases+1)*b_max + nb_phases + b] = G_min[i]
            B[counter] = 0
        
            counter = counter + 1
            A[counter][2*nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases*(b+1) +i] = -1
            A[counter][(3*nb_phases+2)*b_max + nb_phases + b] = G_min[i]
            B[counter] = 0
        
    # ya(b)Gmax(i)>=Ga(i,b), yb(b)Gmax(i)>=Gb(i,b), yc(b)Gmax(i)>=Gc(i,b)
    for b in range(b_max):
        for i in range(nb_phases):
            counter = counter + 1
            A[counter][nb_phases*(b+1) +i] = 1
            A[counter][3*nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases + b] = -G_max[i]
            B[counter] = 0
        
            counter = counter + 1
            A[counter][nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases*(b+1) + i] = 1
            A[counter][(3*nb_phases+1)*b_max + nb_phases + b] = -G_max[i]
            B[counter] = 0
        
            counter = counter + 1
            A[counter][2*nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases*(b+1) +i] = 1
            A[counter][(3*nb_phases+2)*b_max + nb_phases + b] = -G_max[i]
            B[counter] = 0  
        
    # (1-yc(b))t(b)<=(T-1)C+sum(Gi(1:l(jofbuses(b))))+sum(Y(1:l(jofbuses(b))-1))
    for b in range(b_max):
        counter = counter + 1
        A[counter][0:l[jofbuses[b]-1]] = -np.ones((1,l[jofbuses[b]-1]))
        A[counter][(3*nb_phases+2)*b_max+nb_phases+b] = -t[b]
        B[counter] = -t[b] + (T-1)*C + sum(Y[0:l[jofbuses[b]-1]-1])

    # (T-1)C+sum(Gi(1:l(jofbuses(b))))+sum(Y(1:l(jofbuses(b))-1))<=yc(b)t(b)+(1-yc(b))Mbig_1
    for b in range(b_max):
        counter = counter + 1
        A[counter][0:l[jofbuses[b]-1]] = np.ones((1,l[jofbuses[b]-1]))
        A[counter][(3*nb_phases+2)*b_max+nb_phases+b] = -t[b] + Mbig_1
        B[counter] = Mbig_1 - (T-1)*C - sum(Y[0:l[jofbuses[b]-1]-1])


    # -Mbig_2(1-yb(b))<=db(b)=right-hand side of Equation (6)
    for b in range(b_max):
        counter = counter + 1
        constant = q[jofbuses[b]-1]/s[jofbuses[b]-1]*(t[b] - (T-1)*C + sum(G_previous[l[jofbuses[b]-1]:nb_phases]) + sum(Y[l[jofbuses[b]-1] -1:nb_phases]))+ (T-1)*C + sum(Y[0:k[jofbuses[b]-1]-1]) - t[b]  
        A[counter][0:k[jofbuses[b]-1]-1] = -np.ones((1,k[jofbuses[b]-1]-1))
        A[counter][(3*nb_phases+1)*b_max + nb_phases + b] = Mbig_2
        B[counter] = constant + Mbig_2


    # db(b)<=Mbig_2 yb(b)
    for b in range(b_max):
        counter = counter + 1
        constant = q[jofbuses[b]-1]/s[jofbuses[b]-1]*(t[b] - (T-1)*C +sum(G_previous[l[jofbuses[b]-1]:nb_phases]) + sum(Y[l[jofbuses[b]-1] -1:nb_phases]))+ (T-1)*C + sum(Y[0:k[jofbuses[b]-1]-1]) - t[b]  
        A[counter][0:k[jofbuses[b]-1]-1] = np.ones((1,k[jofbuses[b]-1]-1))
        A[counter][(3*nb_phases+1)*b_max + nb_phases + b] = -Mbig_2
        B[counter] = -constant
    
    #Lower Bound LB
    LB_zeros = np.zeros(3*b_max*(nb_phases+1))
    G_min = np.array(G_min)
    LB = np.append(G_min, LB_zeros)

    #Upper Bound UB
    UB = np.ones(3*b_max)
    G_max = np.array(G_max)
    for i in range(3*b_max+1):
        UB = np.concatenate((G_max,UB))
    
    xinit = np.array([(a+b)/2 for a, b in zip(UB, LB)])
    sol = MINLP(xinit, A, B, A_eq, B_eq, LB ,UB, t, ob, jofbuses, q, qc, s, oa, k, l, T, G_previous, C, Y, G_previous)
    
def objective_fun(x, t, ob, jofbuses, q, qc, s, oa, k, l, T, G_next, C, Y, G_previous):
    nb_phases = len(G_next)
    b_max = len(t)
    no_lanegroups = len(q)
    obj = 0
    obj_a = 0
    obj_b = 0

    G = x[0:nb_phases]

    for j in range(no_lanegroups):
        delay_a = 0.5*q[j]/(1-q[j]/s[j]) * (pow((sum(G_previous[l[j]:nb_phases]) + sum(G[0:k[j]-1]) + sum(Y[l[j]-1:nb_phases]) + sum(Y[0:k[j]-1])),2) + pow(sum(G[l[j]:nb_phases]) + sum(G_next[0:k[j]-1]) + sum(Y[l[j]-1:nb_phases]) + sum(Y[0:k[j]-1]),2))   
    
        obj = obj + oa*delay_a
        obj_a = obj_a + oa*delay_a
         
    for b in range(b_max): 
   
        delay_b1 = x[(3*nb_phases+1)*b_max + nb_phases + b]*(q[jofbuses[b]-1]/s[jofbuses[b]-1] * (t[b] - (T-1)*C + sum(G_previous[l[jofbuses[b]-1]:nb_phases]) + sum(Y[l[jofbuses[b]-1] -1:nb_phases])) + (T-1)*C - t[b] + sum(Y[0:k[jofbuses[b]-1]-1])) 
        delay_b2 = x[(3*nb_phases+2)*b_max + nb_phases + b-1]*(q[jofbuses[b]-1]/s[jofbuses[b]-1] * (t[b] - (T-1)*C - sum(Y[0:l[jofbuses[b]-1]-1])) + T*C + sum(G_next[0:k[jofbuses[b]-1]-1]) + sum(Y[0:k[jofbuses[b]-1]-1]) - t[b]) 
        delay_b3 = sum(x[nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases*b:nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases*b+k[jofbuses[b]-1]-1]) - q[jofbuses[b]-1]/s[jofbuses[b]-1]*sum(x[2*nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases*b:2*nb_phases*b_max + nb_phases*b +l[jofbuses[b]-1]])
        delay_b = delay_b1+delay_b2 +delay_b3 

        obj = obj + delay_b*ob[b]
        obj_b = obj_b + delay_b*ob[b]
    return obj
    
def MINLP(xinit, A, B, A_eq, B_eq, LB ,UB, t, ob, jofbuses, q, qc, s, oa, k, l, T, G_next, C, Y, G_previous):
    nb_phases = len(G_next)
    b_max = len(t)
    ## First Solver: IPOPT to get an initial guess
    m_IPOPT = GEKKO(remote = True)
    m_IPOPT.options.SOLVER = 3 #(IPOPT)

    # Array Variable
    rows  = nb_phases + 3*b_max*(nb_phases+1)#48
    x_initial = np.empty(rows,dtype=object)

    for i in range(3*nb_phases*b_max+nb_phases+1):
        x_initial[i] = m_IPOPT.Var(value = xinit[i], lb = LB[i], ub = UB[i])#, integer = False)

    for i in range(3*nb_phases*b_max+nb_phases+1, (3*nb_phases+3)*b_max+nb_phases):
        x_initial[i] = m_IPOPT.Var(value = xinit[i], lb = LB[i], ub = UB[i])#, integer = True)

    # Constraints
    m_IPOPT.axb(A,B,x_initial,etype = '<=',sparse=False) 

    m_IPOPT.axb(A_eq,B_eq,x_initial,etype = '=',sparse=False)

    # Objective Function
    f = objective_fun(x_initial, t, ob, jofbuses, q, qc, s, oa, k, l, T, G_next, C, Y, G_previous)
    m_IPOPT.Obj(f)

    #Solver
    m_IPOPT.solve(disp = True)

####################################################################################################
    ## Second Solver: APOPT to solve MINLP
    m_APOPT = GEKKO(remote = True)
    m_APOPT.options.SOLVER = 1 #(APOPT)

    x = np.empty(rows,dtype=object)

    for i in range(3*nb_phases*b_max+nb_phases+1):
        x[i] = m_APOPT.Var(value = x_initial[i], lb = LB[i], ub = UB[i], integer = False)

    for i in range(3*nb_phases*b_max+nb_phases+1, (3*nb_phases+3)*b_max+nb_phases):
        x[i] = m_APOPT.Var(value = x_initial[i], lb = LB[i], ub = UB[i], integer = True)

    # Constraints
    m_APOPT.axb(A,B,x,etype = '<=',sparse=False) 

    m_APOPT.axb(A_eq,B_eq,x,etype = '=',sparse=False)

    # Objective Function
    f = objective_fun(x, t, ob, jofbuses, q, qc, s, oa, k, l, T, G_next, C, Y, G_previous)
    m_APOPT.Obj(f)

    #Solver
    m_APOPT.solve(disp = True)

    return x 
    
#Define Parameters

C = 120 
T = 31
b_max = 2
G_base = [12,31,12,11,1,41]
G_max = [106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106]
G_min = [7,3,7,10,0,7]
G_previous = [7.3333333, 34.16763, 7.1333333, 10.0, 2.2008602e-16, 47.365703]
Y = [2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3]
jofbuses = [9,3]
k = [3,1,6,4,1,2,5,4,2,3]
l = [3,2,6,5,1,3,6,4,3,4]
nb_phases = 6
oa = 1.25
ob = [39,42]
t = [3600.2, 3603.5]
q = [0.038053758888888886, 0.215206065, 0.11325116416666667, 0.06299876472222223,0.02800455611111111,0.18878488361111112,0.2970903402777778, 0.01876728472222222, 0.2192723663888889, 0.06132227222222222]
qc = [0.04083333333333333, 0.2388888888888889, 0.10555555555555556, 0.0525, 0.030555555555555555, 0.20444444444444446,0.31083333333333335, 0.018333333333333333, 0.12777777777777777, 0.07138888888888889]
s = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]

nb_phases = len(G_base)
G_max = []
for i in range(nb_phases):
    G_max.append(C - sum(Y[0:nb_phases]))

Optimise_G(t,ob, jofbuses, q, qc, s, oa, k, l, T, G_previous, C, Y, G_previous, G_max, G_min)
```

The APOPT solver is successful and returns an integer solution.

```
 APMonitor, Version 1.0.0
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :            2
   Constants    :            0
   Variables    :           48
   Intermediates:            0
   Connections  :           96
   Equations    :            1
   Residuals    :            1
 
 Number of state variables:             48
 Number of total equations: -          105
 Number of slack variables: -            0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :            -57
 
 * Warning: DOF <= 0
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter:     1 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    1 Dpth:    0 Lvs:    3 Obj:  1.64E+04 Gap:       NaN
Iter:     2 I: -1 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    2 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    2 Obj:  1.64E+04 Gap:       NaN
Iter:     3 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    3 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    3 Obj:  1.81E+04 Gap:       NaN
Iter:     4 I: -1 Tm:      0.01 NLPi:    6 Dpth:    1 Lvs:    2 Obj:  1.64E+04 Gap:       NaN
--Integer Solution:   2.15E+04 Lowest Leaf:   1.81E+04 Gap:   1.68E-01
Iter:     5 I:  0 Tm:      0.00 NLPi:    4 Dpth:    2 Lvs:    1 Obj:  2.15E+04 Gap:  1.68E-01
Iter:     6 I: -1 Tm:      0.01 NLPi:    4 Dpth:    2 Lvs:    0 Obj:  1.81E+04 Gap:  1.68E-01
 No additional trial points, returning the best integer solution
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   4.670000000623986E-002 sec
 Objective      :    21455.9882666580     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

If you need to use `remote=False` (local solution) on Linux then the new executable will be available with the new release of Gekko. There are some compiler differences and it appears that the Windows FORTRAN compiler that creates the local `apm.exe` is not as good as the Linux FORTRAN compiler that creates the local `apm` executable. Those executables are in the `bin` folder: `Lib\site-packages\gekko\bin` of the Python folder.

Comment: Dear John, thanks a lot for your answer ! It is working now.