# Gekko - Both "m= gekko(remote=False)" and "m= gekko(remote=True)" are not working

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I am trying to solve a MINLP problem. Initially, I was running the optimization code with m=gekko(remote=True) but since a few days, it's not working anymore.
I get the following error: "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found" then "ImportError: No solution or server unreachable."

When I run it locally using "m= gekko(remote = False)", I get "Exception: Access Violation At line 359 of file ./f90/cqp.f90 Traceback: not available, compile with -ftrace=frame or -ftrace=full Error: 'results.json' not found."

I also tried setting up a server following this tutorial https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/APMonitorServer but without any success.

My code is similar to the one presented here: [GEKKO - timeout error - ImportError: No solution or server unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67840811/gekko-timeout-error-importerror-no-solution-or-server-unreachable)

Can anyone please help me figure out how to solve this issue?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: its probably a network issue not a programming issue

Comment: @Zineb Yes, the main GEKKO server has been offline for a few days now. I expect you are probably finding an issue with the underlying APMonitor executable or the solver. There should be more information available. What do you get when you add `disp=True` to the call to `solve`?

Comment: Thanks @DanielHill for your answer. I have written in the previous post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67840811/gekko-timeout-error-importerror-no-solution-or-server-unreachable) what I get when I set `disp = True`.

Comment: Perfect. Can you update this question with your output so it is a little clearer? I'll answer this one as well so it is easy for people to find in the future.

Comment: Yes sure, I'll edit the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue in this case is an error occurring in APMonitor, which is the underlying executable used by GEKKO for solving the optimization problems. APMonitor or the underlying solver must be crashing and so it is not returning the `results.json` containing the solution.

In this case I would recommend trying a different solver if possible and reporting the error on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO).

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, I just submitted the issue on Github. I was wondering if you have any idea how long this issue may take to be solved? Thanks a lot !