# GEKKO: Access Violation or Connection Variable A Not Found Errors for bsplines

Tags: python, simulation, gekko

I have a model with starting values for fluid state. Basically, I want to use CoolProp in my model to calculate the state variables (a follow-up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76883457/gekko-differentiation-with-coolprop)). When I try to calculate the pressure and the temperature, I get *Exception: Access Violation* . I don't get why it doesn't work. Any help?

```
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.arange(1,3,0.5)
p_scale = 1e5
p_range = np.arange(0.9,2.5, 0.1) #bar
D_range = np.arange(PropsSI('D','P',p_range[-1]*p_scale,'Q',0,"Nitrogen"),PropsSI('D','P',p_range[-1]*p_scale,"T",75,"Nitrogen"), 0.5)
T_range = np.arange(75,PropsSI('T','P',p_range[-1]*p_scale,"Q",0,"Nitrogen"), 0.1) 
u_range = np.arange(PropsSI('U','P',p_range[-1]*p_scale,'T',75,"Nitrogen")/1e3,
                    (PropsSI('D','P',p_range[-1]*p_scale,"Q",0,"Nitrogen")+1)/1e3, 1) #kJ/kg   
p_data,T_data = [], []
for n in D_range:
    row_p,row_T = [],[]
    for i in T_range:
        row_p.append(PropsSI('P','D',n,'T',i,"Nitrogen")/p_scale)
    for i in u_range: row_T.append(PropsSI('T','D',n,'U',i*1e3,"Nitrogen"))
    p_data.append(row_p)
    T_data.append(row_T)
T = m.Var(value=80)
p = m.Var()
D=m.Param(value=793.97)
u=m.Param(value=-116.57)
m.bspline(D,u,T,D_range,u_range,T_data) #T
m.bspline(D,T,p,D_range,T_range,p_data) #p
m.options.SOLVER = 3 # solver (IPOPT) 
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve(disp=False)
```

> Error: Exception: Access Violation
> At line 3157 of file custom.f90
> Traceback: not available, compile with -ftrace=frame or -ftrace=full
>
> Error: 'results.json' not found. Check above for additional error details

It does seem like the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67431986/gekko-minlp-error-options-json-file-not-found) 2 years ago, where the solver crashed...

Comment: `Access Violation At line 3157 of file custom.f90` looks like an internal error somewhere in the underlying FORTRAN code. I'd file an issue to the gekko devs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a work-around until the bug is fixed:

```py
T2 = m.Var()
m.Equation(T2==T)
m.bspline(D,T2,p,D_range,T_range,p_data)
```

It appears that the problem is using `T` as an output from one `bspline()` function and as an input to another `bspline()` function. Disconnect the two by defining a new equation that links the two.

Here is a complete script that runs successfully with lower resolution for the `coolprops` sampling.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
from CoolProp.CoolProp import PropsSI

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.arange(1,3,0.5)
p_scale = 1e5
p_range = np.arange(0.9,2.5, 1) #bar
D_range = np.arange(PropsSI('D','P',p_range[-1]*p_scale,'Q',0,"Nitrogen"),PropsSI('D','P',p_range[-1]*p_scale,"T",75,"Nitrogen"), 5)
T_range = np.arange(75,PropsSI('T','P',p_range[-1]*p_scale,"Q",0,"Nitrogen"), 1) 
u_range = np.arange(PropsSI('U','P',p_range[-1]*p_scale,'T',75,"Nitrogen")/1e3,
                    (PropsSI('D','P',p_range[-1]*p_scale,"Q",0,"Nitrogen")+1)/1e3, 10) #kJ/kg   
p_data,T_data = [], []
for n in D_range:
    row_p,row_T = [],[]
    for i in T_range:
        row_p.append(PropsSI('P','D',n,'T',i,"Nitrogen")/p_scale)
    for i in u_range: row_T.append(PropsSI('T','D',n,'U',i*1e3,"Nitrogen"))
    p_data.append(row_p)
    T_data.append(row_T)
    
T = m.Var(value=80)
p = m.Var()
D=m.Param(value=793.97)
u=m.Param(value=-116.57)
m.bspline(D,u,T,D_range,u_range,T_data) #T
T2 = m.Var()
m.Equation(T2==T)
m.bspline(D,T2,p,D_range,T_range,p_data) #p
m.options.SOLVER = 3 # solver (IPOPT) 

m.open_folder()
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve(disp=True)
```

A new [GitHub issue](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/issues/173) is created to track the resolution of this bug.